# Method doesn't go through 2d array

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am doing a method that goes through a 2d array like a maze and the goal is to reach the position containing the integer 0. I am able to document the path, but it won't move, it stays at the initial position. 
 
Here is an example of what I mean by doesn't move:

```
Please input the size of the board (between 5 and 20):
5
Please choose a starting index from the 4 options below:
    Press 1 for "top-left"
    Press 2 for "top-right"
    Press 3 for "bottom-left"
    Press 4 for "bottom-rigth"
Enter your choice:
1
2   1   1   1   4   
2   3   4   1   3   
1   1   1   2   4   
3   0   3   3   2   
3   2   3   4   2   
Move south 2, Move north 2, Move east 2, Move west 2,
```

Can someone help me please? 
Here is my method so far:

```
public static boolean MagicBoard_recursive(int[][] board, int size, int startRow, int startCol) {
        boolean solvable = true;
        int number = board[startRow][startCol];

        int[] moves = {startRow+number, startRow-number, startCol+number, startCol-number}; // This array contains all the possible moves we can do
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            // If we reached the position containing the integer 0
            if(board[startRow][startCol] == 0) {
                solvable = true;
                break;
            }
            if(startRow+number > size && startRow-number < 0 && startCol+number > size && startCol-number<0) {
                solvable = false;
                break;
            }
            solvable = true;
            // If we try moving south
            if(i == 0) {
                //int destinationNumber = board[startRow+number][startCol];
                // If we move to this position, will we be able to continue, if not, then we try another move
                if(startRow+number > size) {
                    solvable = false;
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    while(solvable) {
                        startRow +=number;
                        System.out.print("Move south " + number + ", ");
                        MagicBoard_recursive(board, size, startRow, startCol);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // If try moving north
            else if(i == 1) {
                // If we move to this position, will we be able to continue. If not, then we try another move
                if(startRow-number < 0) {
                    solvable = false;
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    while(solvable) {
                        startRow -=number;
                        System.out.print("Move south " + number + ", ");
                        MagicBoard_recursive(board, size, startRow, startCol);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // If try moving east
            else if(i == 2) {
                if(startCol+number > size) {
                    solvable = false;
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    while(solvable) {
                        startCol += number;
                        System.out.print("Move east " + number + ", ");
                        MagicBoard_recursive(board, size, startRow, startCol);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // If try moving west
            else if(i == 3) {
                if(startCol-number < 0) {
                    solvable = false;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    while(solvable) {
                        startCol -=number;
                        System.out.print("Move west " + number + ", ");
                        MagicBoard_recursive(board, size, startRow, startCol);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return solvable;
    }
```

Here is a picture that shows an example of the movement that the program would do to solve a board:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I feel like you further need to clarify how movement can happen. I still don't quite understand the desired movement mechanics.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari, I will try to explain myself a little better. What I have to do is a board that contains random numbers that are smaller or equal to the dimension of the board and there is one position that contains an integer 0. Depending on the starting position chosen by the user, there may or may not be a possible path to the position that contains the integer 0. I have to document the path taken by the program if it is possible to solve it. If there is no possible path to reach the 0, then I have to return false. Is my explanation clearer?

Comment: What makes a legal move? For example, in #1 I move South. Why does it go all the way to the bottom of the board in #2?

Comment: @NomadMaker The circle marks the start position on the board. The integer in the circled square indicates that the circle can move a certain number of squares on the board. In one step the circle can move either east, west, north or south. At each step the chosen direction is fixed. The circle cannot move off the board. The only legal start positions are the four corner squares. The board must contain exactly one goal square with 0 as value that can be located anywhere on the board.

Comment: @Jennifer I think there is a much simpler way to solve this problem using queues and something similar to a breadth-first search.

Comment: @Jennifer I ran your code with the initial example board value: Move east 2, Move west 1, Move east 1, Move west 1, Move east 1,.... StackOverFlow exception.  Since you're deciding  which direction to go on the fly, It gets stuck in a loop and ends up blowing the call stack of the recursive calls. Either You need to  find the locaiton of the Zero first and adjust your algorithm to get to that destination or you need to keep track of your own movements via something like a  visited-map   of your board to avoid being stuck in a loop. Or keep the direction of your movement to avoid going back

Comment: @Jennifer There is another problem I spotten on your code. in "for(int i : moves) "   i corresponds to values inside the moves array, not an index. You coded as if "i" is index. For that you need to use (int i=0;i<4;i++) so that you can choose your direction. In short when values in "moves" does not match up with 0,1,2 or 3 it doesn't enter any of those if structures. Overall, as I suggested above and someone showed in the answer below, you need to keep track of the cells you visited so that you can decide more correctly which direction to go.

Comment: @AntiqTech, you are right, I am going to correct my mistake

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you are taking is more difficult than it needs to be.

Consider instead of a *int[][]* array representing the board use something like *Tile[][]* where Tile is a class containing the following properties.

```
public class Tile {
    boolean visited;
    int value; //Maybe short will suffice instead?
}
```

The point of the visited property is to ensure you don't repeatedly test reachable tiles that you already visited before, as in a breadth-first or depth-first search.

Then you might have a class that makes use of a Queue. It's been a while for me and Java but a candidate seems like ArrayDeque for this situation (due to it's resizability). In the class containing your method you would add this as a member.

```
ArrayDeque<TileCoordinate> tilesToVisit = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

The TileCoordinate object is simply a class containing the coordinates for your object. You can instead put the coordinate directly into Tile if you wish to but I prefer to keep them separate.

```
public class TileCoordinate
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public TileCoordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Then here's how this can help simplify your problem. When the user first chooses the starting corner you instead insert the coordinate into your queue rather than processing it directly. Following that you can create a loop which visits any coordinate that is in the queue.

```
//Get input regarding starting corner from user then,
tilesToVisit.add(new TileCoordinate(x, y)); //Insert coordinate corner into queue

while (!tilesToVisit.isEmpty && solvable == false) {
    TileCoordinate tileToVisit = tilesToVisit.removeFirst();
        
    Visit(tileToVisit); //This is where your business logic happens
}

//If loop is completed before solvable is set to true, this means it's not solvable
```

Then in your process method you would want to apply your movement logic to determine what else to visit in your queue.

```
public static void Visit(TileCoordinate coord) {
    Tile tile = board[coord.x, coord.y];
    tile.visited = true; //Make sure you do this first so you don't process this again later!
    
    if (tile.value == 0) {
        //mark solvable to true, which would be a class state variable
    }
    
    //Foreach tile that is reachable from this tile where visited = false, add into your queue 'unvisitedReachableTileCoordinate'
    tilesToVisit.Add(unvisitedReachableTileCoordinate);
}
```

I apologize I haven't coded Java in a while and my netbeans setup is messed up. However I did lookup many of these functions in oracle documentation so it should generally work. This should give you the general idea of this approach.